# Insert data based on a condition

Tags: .net, postgresql, dapper

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to insert a list of objects into a table, using Dapper, but also applying some kind of check to see which data should be included.

```
var data = new List<TestInsertDataDto>
{
    new TestInsertDataDto { InsertId = 1, Value = 2 },
    new TestInsertDataDto { InsertId = 2, Value = 3 },
    new TestInsertDataDto { InsertId = 3, Value = 6 }
};

await connection.ExecuteAsync(@"
    INSERT INTO test_data (insertid, value)
    VALUES (@InsertId, @Value)
    -- I'd like to do a row per row check here to determine if the row should be
    -- inserted or if this row for some reason shouldn't be inserted. This check
    -- requires a query on the test_data table and a join on another table.", data)
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert your record conditionally based on another query with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`.
This would look like:

```
INSERT INTO test_data (insertid, value)
SELECT @InsertId, @Value
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM test_data
    WHERE -- some condition
)
```

Comment: Would I be able to do a "row per row" check there? Like `FROM test_data td WHERE @Value > td.value OR @InsertId > td.insertid`

Comment: This check would be performed "row per row". This function would return the affected records, so you can check it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. I would suggest you to create a stored procedure for this. pass the parameter to the procedure using dapper and try something like below code in your stored procedure

```
INSERT INTO table (id, val) SELECT @InsertId, @Value WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE -- your condition )
```